# Equals Encryption/Decryption AES ECB in C# and PHP

Tags: c#, php, cryptography, aes

Can anyone help me with decryption data (C#) encrypted in PHP?

In PHP im use function:

```
public function encryptString($str) {
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('rijndael_128', 'ecb');
    $pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
    $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    $res = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

    return $res;
}
```

Also in Java i use:

```
public byte[] encryptBytes(byte[] source) {
        try {
            byte[] raw = key.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(source);

            return encrypted;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My C# Code:

```
public string encryptString(string data, string key) 
{
    byte[] keyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
    byte[] toEncryptArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged();
    rDel.Key = keyArray;
    rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    ICryptoTransform cTransform = rDel.CreateEncryptor();
    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
}
```

Key - 32-characters string.

I could not correctly decrypt encrypted data in C#.

Comment: where is your C# code?

Comment: C# method for encryption: http://pastebin.com/ZCGKn6zC
Relult data is not equals using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You C# is using strings instead of byte arrays. This is different from e.g. your Java code. However

```
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
```

will loose data when the ciphertext contains bytes that are not valid encoding for UTF-8.

Furthermore I would urge you to use `CryptoStream` in your C# code; the .NET cryptographic libraries seem to be centered around a streaming approach (for good or bad).